# Defining permissions from database

Tags: abp

I need to load permission definitions from database.
Permission definition provider is in application.contracts and it does not have access to repository.
Where is the best place to load permissions from database on startup?

Comment: I believe you can solve your problem by reading [this](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Data-Seeding) article.

Comment: Thank you. I'll read.